# Creating a list with ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I have two other apps that use a `ListView` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`. The code is almost the exact same. So I decided to use it again on a third app. It is not working, and cannot find a solution.

The problem is that there is nothing displayed in the list. I use a button to add information into the database. I was logging a count on the cursor `Log.d("",storyCur.count()+"");` to make sure the database was being updated and it is.

Relevant Database Code:

```
public Cursor fetchAll(){
  return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_DETAILS,KEY_TITLE},
  null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Rest of relevant code:

```
ListView lv;
DbAdapter db;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   db = new DbAdapter(this);
....
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    db.open();
    fillData();
}

private void fillData(){
    Cursor storyCur = db.fetchAll();
    startManagingCursor(storyCur);

    String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_LOC};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.row1};

   SimpleCursorAdapter stories = 
      newSimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.story_row,storyCur,from,to);

   lv.setAdapter(stories);

    storyCur.close();
}
```

main XML:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

story_row XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/row1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:background="#444444" />
```

Comment: Why are you closing your cursor immediately after you initialize the adapter? I believe you should remove the call to .close() on the cursor. SimpleCursorAdapter will manage that for you and requires an open cursor

Comment: Wow. I don't know why I had that. I had it in my other 2 apps and they worked fine. That solved it, though. Thank you. You could post an answer if you want the rep. Thanks again.

Comment: posted as answer. I'm pretty sure you don't need to call startManagingCursor(storyCur) either but that may only be in newer versions of the SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call to .close() on the cursor. SimpleCursorAdapter needs the cursor to be open in order to function and will call close() on the cursor for you.